# Repeat given array to more complex shape

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I want to create an array of shape `(3, 3, 4)`. The data to populate the array with is given.

My solution right now works perfectly fine but feels like I am missing a numpy lesson here. I do not want to do multiple `.repeat()`s over and over.

```py
start = np.linspace(start=10, stop=40, num=4)
arr = np.repeat([start], 3, axis=0)
arr = np.repeat([arr], 3, axis=0)
arr

# output
array([[[10., 20., 30., 40.],
        [10., 20., 30., 40.],
        [10., 20., 30., 40.]],

       [[10., 20., 30., 40.],
        [10., 20., 30., 40.],
        [10., 20., 30., 40.]],

       [[10., 20., 30., 40.],
        [10., 20., 30., 40.],
        [10., 20., 30., 40.]]])
```

Comment: There is a `np.tile` function, but it too uses multiple repeats.  Repeat is a compiled function, so is relatively fast.  If `start` has shape (1,1,4), you can call repeat with different axis value, or use `tile` (with (3,3,1).

Answer (score 1):

The array mentioned by you can be created by first creating a 1D array with `np.linspace()` and then using `np.tile()` to repeat that array in the required shape.

Following is the updated code:

```
import numpy as np

start = np.linspace(start=10, stop=40, num=4)
arr = np.tile(start, (3, 3, 1))

print(arr)
```

I think this is a more concise way to create the array you require.

Following is the output that you get:

```
[[[10. 20. 30. 40.]
  [10. 20. 30. 40.]
  [10. 20. 30. 40.]]

 [[10. 20. 30. 40.]
  [10. 20. 30. 40.]
  [10. 20. 30. 40.]]

 [[10. 20. 30. 40.]
  [10. 20. 30. 40.]
  [10. 20. 30. 40.]]]
```

In the above code, `np.tile()` is used to repeat the `start` array in the shape of `(3, 3, 1)`. The last dimension `(1)` is added to match the required shape of `(3, 3, 4)` and distribute the values correctly.

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways to create your desired array, but keep in mind that your array could automagically function like a `(3, 3, 4)` shaped array in many contexts due to [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

In this case, I think the most elegant way to create your desired array is to "force" the broadcasting via [`np.broadcast_to`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html):

```
import numpy as np

start = np.linspace(start=10, stop=40, num=4)

out = np.broadcast_to(start, (3, 3, 4))
```

out:

```
array([[[10., 20., 30., 40.],
        [10., 20., 30., 40.],
        [10., 20., 30., 40.]],

       [[10., 20., 30., 40.],
        [10., 20., 30., 40.],
        [10., 20., 30., 40.]],

       [[10., 20., 30., 40.],
        [10., 20., 30., 40.],
        [10., 20., 30., 40.]]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option besides tile is to use [broadcast_to](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html). In this case,

```
start = np.linspace(start=10, stop=40, num=4)
arr = np.broadcast_to(start,(3,3,4))
```

leads to the desired result.